# Matching width of colorbox with caption to the corresponding table

Tags: tables, color, captions

Please have a look at the following MEW:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}
\captionsetup[table]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=orange!20}
\captionof{table}{The first table}
\centerline{
\fcolorbox{yellow!20}{yellow!20}{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
  \toprule
  Gender & No.(\%)\\
 \midrule
Female & 4 (21.1) \\ 
  Male & 15 (78.9) \\ 
   \midrule
Total & 19 (100.0) \\ 
   \bottomrule
  \tiny{Source: Airtel Data}
  \end{tabular}
}
}
\end{document}
```

Now the above produces the following:
[image]

But I would like the width of the caption to exactly match the width of the table. Any ideas? [Please ignore the column header, does not match with code but should not matter in this case]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table can be put into a box, whose width is used for a `\parbox` (or `minipage`), which limits the width of the caption:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,booktabs,caption}

\captionsetup[table]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=orange!20}

\newsavebox\measurebox

\begin{document}

\sbox\measurebox{%
  \fcolorbox{yellow!20}{yellow!20}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.4\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
      \toprule
      Gender & No.\@ (\%)\\
      \midrule
      Female & 4 (21.1) \\
      Male & 15 (78.9) \\
      \midrule
      Total & 19 (100.0) \\
      \bottomrule
      \tiny{Source: Airtel Data}
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{center}
  \parbox{\wd\measurebox}{%
    \centering
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
    \captionof{table}{The first table}
    \usebox\measurebox
  }%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The example also removes unwanted spaces by commenting the line ends. These spaces actually matter, because they are set in horizontal mode.
- The spacing around the caption can be removed by setting `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` to zero. (Because the caption is above the table, the logic of "above" and "below" is a little confusingly reversed. `\abovecaptionskip` is used between the caption and the table, thua also a `\vspace{-\abovecaptionskip}` will do.)

Variant with some manual number alignment:

```
Female & \leavevmode\phantom{0}4 \phantom{1}(21.1) \\
Male & 15 \phantom{1}(78.9) \\
```

> [image: Result with manual number alignemnt]

Or

```
Gender &
\sbox{\measurebox}{19 (100.0)}%
\leavevmode\rlap{No.}%
\kern\wd\measurebox
\llap{(\%)}\\
\midrule
Female & \leavevmode\phantom{0}4 \phantom{1}(21.1) \\
Male & 15 \phantom{1}(78.9) \\
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great, it works. About the first table in your answer, anyway to remove the space between the caption and the table? I would like to have the caption right on top of the table without any space between them.